# Calculating probability with given ranges

Tags: php, arrays, probability

In a couple of last application I was supposed to implement Probability which was usually given among some items say:

reward a user on certain level completion item `X`

item `X` may be one of the below:

```
jug => probability 25
glass => probability 50
plate => probability 20
dish => probability 5
```

I solve this by creating an array and populating the specific item the number of times its probability is; for the above case I would have an array with `25 elements of jug, 50 glasses and so on.`. and I finally `shuffle` {PHP} the array a few time and select a random element from it.

in another application the values were totaling more than 100 so I first calculated their respected percentages from that total and then used the above logic.

Just want to know if this is the right way to calculate probability from such a structure?

I have gone through a couple of issues here on SOF but none helped me in my case.

If there is more appropriate way to do this please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply assign the following values:

```
$jug = 25;
$glass = 25+50 = 75;
$plate = 75+20 = 95;
$dish = 95+5 = 100
```

Then obtain a random of 100 and determine where it fits, similar to the **pseudocode** below:

```
$jug = 25;
$glass = 75;
$plate = 95;
$dish = 100;
$items = {"jug", "glass", "plate", "dish"};

$rand = random(100);  // Get a random number between 0 and 100

if ($rand < $jug) {
    return items(0);
} elseif ($rand < $glass) {
    return items(1);
} elseif ($rand < $plate) {
    return items(2);
} elseif ($rand < $dish) {
    return items(3);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this the same way as you, but you don't have to calculate percentages, you may use more than 100 elements.

For example, if A=80 and B=40, you may use the array with 120 elements.

However, in mathematics there is a term [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) that you can reduce the number of elements. In this example, the GCD is 40 so A would be 2 and B would be 1, and your array size would decrease to 3 elements. It might be important for example when total number of elements is quite large.

Comment: awesome! wish I was a maths guy too :S, but, my data wont fit this case am afraid, it has values like, 50, 10, 5.5, 1 and 0.5. In this GCD would be 0.5. I was just looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280514/returning-a-random-value-from-array-with-probability-proportional-to-its-value?rq=1). I am trying to understand the answer it seems quiet easy but m unable to absorb it right now.

Comment: If your values are lower than 1 you need to multiply all of them, in your case by 2, so there is 1 (2*0,5) as GCD, pity. But in the example from the question the GCD is 5, so `jug` is 5, `glass` is 10, `plate` is 4 and `dish` is 1.

Comment: I think the @Florin's solution is better.