# Picking random item from PHP array based on probability

Tags: php

I have a map of users and a count of entries/tickets they have purchased for a raffle (or lottery or any other similar event).

The map of users to entries is in the structure as seen below:

```
// Map the person to the amount of entries they have purchased
$entries = [
    'Adam' => 5,
    'James' => 3,
    'Oliver' => 4,
    'Holly' => 8
];
```

I want to choose a random user but take into consideration their chance based on ticket count. The probability of winning must be:

> (User Ticket Amount / Total Ticket Count) * 100 = Probability percentage

For example, from the test array the expected results is Holly will win the raffle 8 times out of 20 times.

Comment: Do you want the probability returned or a random name?

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: Well, in term of probability can you just build an array with all the person (5 adam, 3 james, etc.) and then just use array_rand ?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica A random name

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth My few attempts logically wasn't going to work so I deleted them, I'm unsure how to go about this

Comment: @MickaëlLeger how would i do that? go over array and then add the user to a new array as many times as they got entries? surely if there are thousands of entries for one user and they have a longer name this can cause parformance issues?

Comment: @AdamZorchubiez Yes sure, if you have a lot of person inside your first array with a lot of possibility it can be problematic ! But i don't have other idea right now sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a coincidence you are asking this as I created a method to do just this the other day when writing a script for a betting site.

Please see the comments for explanation of what the code consists of:

```
// The array passed to the function should be your $entries array
function randProb(array $items) {
  $totalProbability = 0; // This is defined to keep track of the total amount of entries

  foreach ($items as $item => $probability) {
      $totalProbability += $probability;     
  }

  $stopAt = rand(0, $totalProbability); // This picks a random entry to select
  $currentProbability = 0; // The current entry count, when this reaches $stopAt the winner is chosen

  foreach ($items as $item => $probability) { // Go through each possible item
      $currentProbability += $probability; // Add the probability to our $currentProbability tracker
      if ($currentProbability >= $stopAt) { // When we reach the $stopAt variable, we have found our winner
          return $item;
      }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Any questions feel free to ask below, if you would like to output the value (probability) of the winning item, return `$probability` at the breakpoint instead of `$item`

Comment: this is perfect I think this will work... I'm unsure where to put this code though at top of my file?

Comment: @AdamZorchubiez I'm glad I could help

Comment: @JoshWood this can't be completely random , as if `$stopAt` is a little number , like 4 and the user with low probability like 7 , ( assume others above 7 ) can win this if hes first in the list . sort of the items matter , so it's not random

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are trying to do, and is pretty simple to understand.

```
function rand_with_entries($entries) {

    //create a temporary array
    $tmp = [];

    //loop through all names
    foreach($entries as $name => $count) {

        //for each entry for a specific name, add name to `$tmp` array
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {
            $tmp[] = $name;
        }

    }

    //return random name from `$tmp` array
    return $tmp[array_rand($tmp)];
}
```

Comment: Let's hope there won't be too much people buying too much tickets. RAM will suffer a lot

Comment: @Cid I think you would sooner hit your max allowed memory size in many environments before this causes any sort of issues. I tried it on multiple online PHP testers with 300k+ array keys and it spit out the name instantly. On my own personal server it also handled 300k with ease. I would do more, but generating the huge `$entries` array starts to take some time above 300k

Comment: 300k **numeric** or **string** keys ?

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3838237971e0ec9c8cc44ccbc6cb9e4fee0a7b53)

Comment: @Cid Strings, I was using `md5(rand())` for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have this data :

```php
$entries = [
    'Adam' => 5,
    'James' => 3,
    'Oliver' => 4,
    'Holly' => 8
];
```

One way can be to fill an array according to this data and use `array_rand`. Here is an example :

```php
function pickRand($array, $nb) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $name => $probability) {
        $num = $probability;
        while ($num > 0) {
            $newArray[] = $name;
            $num--;
        }
    }
    return $newArray[array_rand($newArray, $nb)];
}
```

And to use it :

```php
$randomName = pickRand($entries, 1);
```

Comment: What is your `$nb` variable? Amount of returns?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica yes, since it's a param in `array_rand`, better to use it in a function I think !